# Sub sequence occurrence in a string

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

Given 2 strings like bangalore and blr, return whether one appears as a subsequence of the other. The above case returns true whereas bangalore and brl returns false.

Comment: no not a homework, first thing I thought of was suffix trie but not sure if it is a good choice so wanted to know what is the first thing that come up to other's mind ?

Answer (score 17):

Greedy strategy should work for this problem.

- Find the first letter of the suspected substring (blr) in the big string (*b*angalore)
- Find the second letter starting at the index of the first letter plus one (anga*l*ore)
- Find the third letter starting at the index of the second letter plus one (o*r*e)
- Continue until you can no longer find the next letter of blr in the string (no match), or you run out of letters in the subsequence (you have a match).

Here is a sample code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string txt = "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    string s = "brownfoxzdog";
    int pos = -1;
    bool ok = true;
    for (int i = 0 ; ok && i != s.size() ; i++) {
        ok = (pos = txt.find(s[i], pos+1)) != string::npos;
    }
    cerr << (ok ? "Found" : "Not found") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess it is not possible in better than O(n)?

Comment: @princessofpersia No, not without preprocessing. If you have a large text, and need to repeatedly query it for substrings, I think you can optimize it somewhat: for each letter of the alphabet, store a sorted list of its occurrences in the text. Then you could do your search in `O(K*logN)`, where `K` is the number of letters in the substring, and `N` is the number of letters in the text.

Comment: logN for binary search of the string ?

Comment: @princessofpersia - logN for binary searching the list of occurrences of a particular letter. That list is O(N) long for each letter. (Actually, O(N/M) where M is the number of letters in the alphabet, but that's assumed here to be a constant.)

Comment: First of all there's no assumption that the string is sorted, so binary search will not work.

Comment: @RafałDowgird "for each letter of the alphabet, store a sorted list of its occurrences in the text." Binary search on that list.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, I misunderstood the context.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Solution 1
public static boolean isSubSequence(String str1, String str2) {
     int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (i < str1.length() && j < str2.length()) {
            if (str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j)) {
                i++;
                j++;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
    return j == str2.length();
}

// Solution 2 using String indexOf method
public static boolean isSubSequenceUsingIndexOf(String mainStr, String subStr) {
    int i = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while(i<subStr.length()) {
        char c = subStr.charAt(i);
        if((index = mainStr.indexOf(c, index)) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O(N) solution, where N is the length of the substring.

```
bool subsequence( string s1, string s2 ){
    int n1 = s1.length();
    int n2 = s2.length();

    if( n1 > n2 ){
        return false;
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while( i < n1 && j < n2 ){
        if( s1[i] == s2[j] ){
            i++;
        } 
        j++;
    }

    return i == n1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Find the length of the [**longest common subsequence**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem). If it is equal to the length of small string, return true

Comment: That's like taking a sledge hammer to kill a fly! LCS is O(N*M), it will be slower than greedy, especially when there is no match.